# Simple question about montonically increasing function

Tags: functions, examples-counterexamples

Suppose we have a continuous $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$, we know the definition of a monotonically increasing function is for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$, if $x < y$ then $f(x) < f(y)$. I know that if $f(x) < f(y)$ then $x < y$ is not the contra-positive to the statement, so they must not be equivalent. But I am having trouble coming up with a counter example.

If we have f(x) = x, then indeed the two statements are true, what function could we use to show that they are not?

Comment: The contrapositive is inverted _and_ flipped, so....

Comment: What do you mean by "counter-example"? An example of a function which is not monotonically increasing? It sounds like maybe you want to come up with the contrapositive to this definition, not a counterexample....

Comment: Do you want to drop monotonicity for the counter example?

Comment: I thought the two statements that "if x < y then f(x) < f(y)" and "if f(x) < y then x < y" were not equivalent statements. But from answer below they are, so we can't come up with a counter example here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no counter example. Suppose you are given $f(x) < f(y)$. Now either $x=y$ or $x>y$ or $x<y$. But if $x=y$then $f(x)=f(y)$. If $x>y$ then monotonicity gives us $f(x)>f(y)$.

Comment: Ohhh,so the two statements are equivalent?

Comment: yes- that's what the above proof shows.